# Loop in lesscss

Tags: less

```
.whatWeDoLoop(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
    .whatWeDoLoop((@counter - 1));    // next iteration
    .st-theme-icon:nth-child(2n+@counter) {
        -webkit-transition: all (0.3s * @counter) 0.3s;
    }
}
.whatWeDoLoop(4); // launch the loop
.st-theme-icon {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.css3-effect .st-theme-one-page-visible .st-theme-icon {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
}
```

I have 4 columns and want each column has diff transition time.

I try this code but the css file render does not fit with my option.

The result :

```
.st-theme-icon:nth-child(2n+@counter){-webkit-transition:all(0.3s) 0.3s;}
```

Comment: Make it `.st-theme-icon:nth-child(2n+@{counter})` :) You are using a variable for forming a selector (interpolation) and so the `{}` are required.

Comment: Thank you. Can you optimize my code better ?

Comment: Your loop is already pretty good. The second part could be optimized by using a parametric mixin since the properties are same and only values change.

Comment: Yes, thank you for comment about the second part.